# NetSuite Searching for a Duplicate Email Address

Tags: netsuite

As you can tell from all of my earlier questions I'm attempting to learn some NetSuite Suitescript to truly leverage NetSuite. With that being said I've got to where I can search for the max employee number and then act accordingly. Now what I want to do is to search for an email address to see if the one given is a duplicate. Essentially ensure the workflow will not create a new employee record if an employee record already exists with the email address.

I have the following so far...

```
function checkDuplicate(givenEmail){
    var filters = new nlobjSearchFilter('email', null, givenEmail);
    var colums = new nlobjSearchColumn('email');
    var results = new nlobjSearchRecord('employee', null, filters, columns);
    if(results[0].getValue('email') == null) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

Is there a better/easier way? I'll be testing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is a bit off. Based on your script, I suggest apply the following modifications:

```
function checkDuplicate(givenEmail){
    var filters = new nlobjSearchFilter('email', null, 'is', givenEmail);
    var results = new nlapiSearchRecord('employee', null, filters);

    return (results != null);
}
```

Since you're just checking if there are any matching results, an `nlobjColumn` isn't needed. Also, if there aren't any matches, `nlapiSearchRecord` returns a null.

As an additional note, it seems you're still a bit rough on your SuiteScript (at least with the search APIs), so I suggest looking up "Searching with SuiteScript" in the NetSuite Help Center.

Comment: While this is definitely closer, this function doesn't quite tell you that there is a duplicate email; it only tells you that the email exists. To detect duplicates, I would modify the return value of the function slightly:

`return (results && (results.length > 1));`

This ensures `results` is not `null` (`nlapiSearchRecord` returns `null` when there are no matching results) and then checks if there is more than one matching record.

Comment: Yes, though the scenario was to prevent the creation of a new Employee record if an Employee already existed with the same e-mail - hence, return true only if there was a match.

Comment: Ah, my mistake - I was thinking we were looking for emails that were already duplicated. If we're just trying to prevent, your function accomplishes that.